# Is naming an object in a public bucket uid(of user) safe

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I was reading through Google Cloud docs and under best practices for Cloud Storage it states:

> Don't use user IDs, email addresses, project names, project numbers,
>   or any personally identifiable information (PII) in bucket names
>   because anyone can probe for the existence of a bucket. Similarly, be
>   very careful with putting PII in your object names, because object
>   names appear in URLs for the object.

I would like to store currentUser.uid as an object in a bucket, Does the user ID above refer to my own sites generated ID or is it referring to the Google generated uid?